# avoid explorer throw error in srcElement

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

i try avoid explorer throws error in  srcElement, it does not have this function.I have

```
function (event) {
    if (event.srcElement)
    {
        valueThis = event.srcElement.getAttribute("value");
    }
    else if(event.target)
      {
        valueThis = event.target.getAttribute("value");
     }
}
```

but it doesnt work because InternetExplorer throws error in e.srcElement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about IE<9, the `event` object is not passed to listener handler as the first argument. So

```
function(event)
{
    if(!event) alert("Dead");
}
```

will likely "dead" in IE.

A more common way to do this is:

```
function(e)
{
    e=e?e:window.event;
    if(e.target){/*...*/}
    else if(e.srcElement){/*...*/}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the object method `hasOwnProperty(string property)` for this:

```
function (event) {
 if (event.hasOwnProperty('srcElement')) {
    valueThis = event.srcElement.getAttribute("value");
 }
 else if (event.hasOwnProperty('target')) {
  valueThis = event.target.getAttribute("value");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Required field validator on textbox was causing this issue, once I manually validation code. The issue is solved.